# How to change array to an object class?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have cut out the code to shorten the page but I'm asking how do I change personInterests into its own class. Apologies for the vague question but essentially I want to change personInterests in my Person class to a class where personInterests has multiple variables.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class Person{

    private String personName;
    private String[] personInterests = new String[3];

    public Person(String personName, String[] personInterests){
        this.personName = personName;
        this.personInterests = personInterests;
    }   

    public void setInterests(String[] personInterests){
        this.personInterests = personInterests;
    }

    public String[] getInterests(){
        return personInterests;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return personName;
    }


    public String toString(){
        String result = getName() + " ";
        for (String interests : personInterests) {
            result += interests + " ";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This was my idea of how it would work just not sure how I would use this class and call it later on.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class Interests {
    private int interestDangerRating;
    private String interestName;
    private ArrayList<Interests> interestsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Interests (int interestDangerRating ,String interestName){
        this.interestDangerRating = interestDangerRating;
        this.interestName = interestName;
    }

    public void addInterests(Interests p){
        interestsList.add(p);
    }

    Interests getInterests(int i){
        return interestsList.get(i);
    }
```

}

Any help is appreciated, as I said this code has mostly been taken out and this was an old project already completed just wanted to see if I could change some of the features.

Comment: What's wrong with the `Interests` class you created? Can you not just call it from whichever other class? `Interests interests = new Interests;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so here's what I would do to clean this up for you and make it work. Firstly, think about what you are trying to do. You want to create a Person who has multiple Interests, right? So the Interest class, going by your above example, can be changed to be a typical Java object class as follows:

```
public class Interest {
    private int dangerRating;
    private String name;

    public Interest (int dangerRating, String name) {
        this.dangerRating = dangerRating;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getDangerRating() {
        return dangerRating;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

So now we've an `Interest` class set up where you can set a name for your interest and a danger rating. What we need to do, now, is edit your `Person` class so as you can store a **list of interests** for each `Person` you create.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Person{
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Interest> interests = new ArrayList<Interest>();

    public Person(String name, ArrayList<Interest> interests) {
        this.name = name;
        this.interests = interests;
    }   

    public void addInterest(Interest newInterest) {
        interests.add(newInterest);
    }

    public Interest getInterest(int indexOfInterest) {
        return interests.get(indexOfInterest);
    }

    public ArrayList<Interest> getInterests() {
        return interests;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = getName() + " ";
        for(Interest interest : interests) {
            result += interest.getName() + "(" + interest.getDangerRating() + ")" + " ";
        }
        return result.trim();
    }
}
```

This allows you to set an initial list of all interests for your new `Person` and, from there, you can add new interests, get all interests or get any individual interest.

Hope this helps to clarify for you how this should all fit together!

So now it's time to instantiate everything. Lets create some `Interest`objects which we will use:

```
Interest golf = new Interest(1, "golf");
Interest swimming = new Interest(3, "swimming");
```

Now lets assume we want two people called John and Mary. John likes golf and swimming while Mary only likes swimming. We'd then create their list of `Interest` as follows:

```
ArrayList<Interest> johnsInterests = new ArrayList<Interest>();
johnsInterests.add(golf);
johnsInterests.add(swimming);

ArrayList<Interest> marysInterests = new ArrayList<Interest>();
marysInterests.add(swimming);
```

And finally, we'd then create our two `Person` objects which will include the persons name and interests list.

```
Person john = new Person("John", johnsInterests);
Person mary = new Person("Mary", marysInterests);
```

And voila!

Comment: how do i call this in my main class? so if im creating a new person                          `  Person[] newPerson = new Person[1]; 
  newPerson[0] = new Person(String name, ArrayList<Interest> interests)` what do I put in the arrayList bit if I hard code call it

Comment: I've now added a bit extra to my initial comment to show how to instantiate everything and put it all together.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah i figured it out anyway but appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

First, make an `Interest`class:

```
public class Interest {
   private int interestDangerRating;
   private String interestName;
   // .. getters and setters 
    }
```

then in the `Person`class get rid of `private String[] personInterests = new String[3];`

and replace it by:

```
  private ArrayList<Interest> interestsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting there with the logic of your Interests class, but it needs a few changes

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class Interests {

private int interestDangerRating;

// Is this a unique name for the entire class? If yes then no worries, but if not 
// then its not needed, you've already got a list of interest names below
private String interestName;

// Change the array list to hold Strings, it's a list of words
private ArrayList<String> interestsList = new ArrayList<>();

public Interests (int interestDangerRating ,String interestName){
    this.interestDangerRating = interestDangerRating;
    this.interestName = interestName;
}

public void addInterest(String p){ // Again, change this to String
    interestsList.add(p);
}

String getInterest(int i){ // Change this to return a String, since we changed the ArrayList above
    return interestsList.get(i);
}
}
```

There's alot more you need to think about with this class too. How do you know how many interests are in the list, should there be a length variable? Or what about a method that returns the entire list of interests rather than just 1?

Also, there's only one interestDangerRating being set in this class; if each interest has a different danger rating, should't you be adding a danger rating for every interest?

In terms of accessing your new class, you'll need to create a class in your code by:

```
Interests variableName = new Interests(1, "football");
```

I have randomly chosen '1' and 'football' above, since they are in your Interest class' constructor. The way your class is built, you cannot use it without providing an int and a String when the object is made

Finally, to call methods on your class, you use the variable created above to call its methods:

```
variableName.addInterest("basketball");

String interest = variableName.getInterest(1);
```

If you're struggling, I recommend looking at a simple java tutorial online. instatiating java classes and calling their methods like this are fundamental concepts in Java :)

Comment: Thank you, I knouw youre not suppoes to put that put it was very helpful and I used it